# Inverse Kinematics for tail rig not working

Tags: rigging, armature

I was following tutorial on Youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-qVNEKEDJs&t=702s At the part when they added the Inverse Kinematic, i couldn't make it work like the tutorial. I can't make the whole tail moves.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UWGaRd4t7LpQavFpq3BBdsHQ1Zi16su-/view?usp=share_link the .blend file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply select the IK controller bone, go to edit mode and press Alt P > Clear parent.

A controller bone cannot be child of a bone of the Ik chain, as it would create a "Circular dependency", where moving the IK would move the parent, which would move the controller, which would move .........

Comment: Thanks! it worked.